# Itterate through List of objects recieved in JSON

Tags: java, codenameone

I have the following JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "siteName": "site1",
    "addressLine1": "address1",
    "addressLine2": "address2",
    "town": "town1",
    "postcode": "postcode1",
    "contactName": "name1",
    "contactNumber": "number1",
    "contactEmail": "email1"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "siteName": "site2",
    "addressLine1": "address1",
    "addressLine2": "address2",
    "town": "town1",
    "postcode": "postcode1",
    "contactName": "name1",
    "contactNumber": "number1",
    "contactEmail": "email1"
  },
]
```

I'm parsing the data but it simply outputs one long string.  I'd like to access each element within each object.

UPDATE: I'm outputting the individual elements, but for some reason the 'id' property is considered a double?

```
Map<String,Object> jsonArr = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));

java.util.List<Map<String, Object>> content = (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>)jsonArr.get("root");

 for(Map<String, Object> obj : content) {

                                Log.p((int)obj.get("id"));
                                Log.p((String)obj.get("siteName"));
                                Log.p((String)obj.get("addressLine1"));
                                Log.p((String)obj.get("addressLine2"));
                                Log.p((String)obj.get("town"));
                                Log.p((String)obj.get("postcode"));
                                Log.p((String)obj.get("contactName"));
                                Log.p((String)obj.get("contactNumber"));
                                Log.p((String)obj.get("contactEmail"));
                            }
```

Comment: Also, I'm not sure I recognize what library this is. Can you please specify it?

Comment: Its codename one

Comment: Then the answer is right in the [docs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/JSONParser.html#parseJSON-java.io.Reader-). You need to extract the root element (`items.get("root")`) and *then* iterate the result.

Comment: which library are you using @AHoughton ?

Comment: @Deadpool they already said, Codename One.

Comment: Thanks for that Federico

Comment: For the double values first make sure to invoke `JSONParser.setUseLongs(true)` which will return `Long` objects where appropriate. If you want an int value regardless use `Util.toIntValue(Object)` it will safely convert any object type to an int. There are similar utility methods for every type. This is used by properties which are far more convenient for JSON parsing e.g.: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties-are-amazing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using Codename One, `parseJSON` *always* returns a `Map<String, Object>`, but behaves differently when the root element is an array. In that case, the returned `Map` contains an object whose key is `"root"` which you then can iterate on to obtain the actual objects.

```
Map<String, Object> data = json.parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(
    new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));

List<Map<String, Object>> content = (java.util.List<Map<String, Object>>)data.get("root");

for(Map<String, Object> obj : content) {
    Log.p(obj.getValue().toString());
}
```

For further info see the [documentation](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/JSONParser.html#parseJSON-java.io.Reader-) for the `parseJSON` method.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an array of objects as it stats with `[` and ends with `]`. You have to try like this.

```
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONParser().parseJSON(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(r.getResponseData()), "UTF-8"));
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArr.length(); i++) {
                String siteName = jsonArr.getJSONObject(i).getString("siteName");
                System.out.println(siteName);
 }
```

Comment: Please check the comments, OP is using a specific library, which makes the code in your answer wrong.